# Entering float data into my SQL server through Visual Studio 2012 causes error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, double, number-formatting

I have a table in a MS SQL 2012 which was created in Visual Studio 2012 through SQL Server Data Tools and has some float fields.

Now, I want to populate it also in Visual Studio, but when I enter a float value it says:
[image]

At home I have Visual Studio 2010 with SQL Server 2008 and everything is working as expected.

Comment: And you are using '.' when your locale specifies ',' as the decimal separator or vice-versa ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error here. This is the expected behavior for all Windows applications. String to number or date conversions use the user's regional settings.

You almost certainly have different regional settings on your work and home computer and you tried to enter a number using the wrong decimal separator, eg '.' instead of ',' or vice versa.